# Drop-down list of hyperlinks to other sheets in other workbooks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Through this code

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.source.getActiveSheet() && e.range.getRow() === 1 && e.range.getColumn() === 1) {
    e.source.getSheetByName(e.value).activate();
  }
}

function sheetnames() {
  var out = new Array()
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++) out.push( [ sheets[i].getName() ] )
  return out 
}
```

I can switch tabs via the drop-down list. That is, if I select the name 'sheet 2' from the drop-down list, it redirects me to sheet 2

I wanted to know if it is possible to modify this code, so that when I select a certain option in the drop-down list, it takes me to another worksheet (instead of a tab)

Comment: Please show that you have tried to achieve what is being asked and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When a dropdown list of the cell "D7" on the sheet "Formulário" is changed to `Sucesso do Cliente`, you want to open `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BbuJfPPOSdbvHZ5b8xVTMndeydNfslDhPLm9ftL1pLU/edit?usp=sharing`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet of "In this worksheet:". And, [please install OnEdit trigger to the function `installedOnEdit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually). When you use this script, please change a dropdown list of the cell "D7" on the sheet "Formulário" to `Sucesso do Cliente`. By this, the script is run.

```js
function installedOnEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != "Formulário" || range.getA1Notation() != "D7" || range.getValue() != "Sucesso do Cliente") return;
  const url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BbuJfPPOSdbvHZ5b8xVTMndeydNfslDhPLm9ftL1pLU/edit?usp=sharing";
  const html = `<script>window.open('${url}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "sample");
}
```

- When you change a dropdown list of the cell "D7" on the sheet "Formulário" to `Sucesso do Cliente`, a dialog is opened, and the URL of `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BbuJfPPOSdbvHZ5b8xVTMndeydNfslDhPLm9ftL1pLU/edit?usp=sharing` is opened by Javascript of the dialog.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the URL you expected is opened. But, the 1st Spreadsheet cannot be closed.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: When I run the code, I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined". How to solve?

Sorry, I'm not very good at coding.

Comment: @Melo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and for my poor English skill. About `When I run the code, I get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined"`, I think that the reason for your current issue is due to that you might directly run my sample script. In this case, such an error occurs because of no event object. In my sample script, from your question, the script is run by the installed OnEdit trigger. So, please install the OnEdit trigger to the function and edit the dropdown list. By this, the script is automatically run.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!

Could you help me one more time?

How can I apply this code to all items in my dropdown list? Is there a way to do this?

My dropdown list at ten items in total and each has a worksheet to redirect to

Answer (score 1):

#### Combining the onEdit functions

This function allow you to jump to other sheets in the same spreadsheet using the datavalidation of A1 and to different sheets of other spreadsheet using datavalidation of B1

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value ) {
    const shts = {"Sheet1":"1553288907","Sheet2":"1273539231"};
    //e.source.toast('Flag1');
    const url = `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11yNxdh/edit#gid=${shts[e.value]}?usp=sharing`;
    //Logger.log(url);
    const html = `<script>window.open('${url}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script>`;
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "sample");
  }
  if(e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value) {
    e.source.getSheetByName(e.value).activate();
  }
}
```

In my example I used data validation from a list Sheet1,Sheet2 and you could add id to the shts object and insert it into the url with something like ${shts[e.value][id]}