# Can I Open a URL automatically from a DropDown in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown

Right now I have a dropdown list which populates an adjacent cell with a URL based on what is selected.  I then just mouseover the link and click to open it in a browser.  I'm wondering if I can elimate this last step by having the URL open automatically in a browser once a selection is made in the drop down?

Not sure what to try. A search did not reveal an answer. If I missed it somewhere please post a link to the thread.

Comment: Apps script will do. Get the function to run on edit basis, but with a different name other than `onEdit()` and have it triggered via an installable trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `OnEdit` Trigger, this will open the link automatically in a browser once selection is made:

```
function openLink(e) {
  var sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == "A2") { //Cell where dropdown is

    var url = sh.getRange("B2").getValue(); //Adjacent to dropdown in my example
    const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<html><script>window.open('${url}', '_blank');google.script.host.close();</script></html>`).setHeight(30).setWidth(50);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Opening...");

  }
}
```

**RESULT:**

[image]

*REF:* [Drop-down list of hyperlinks to other sheets in other workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72419838/drop-down-list-of-hyperlinks-to-other-sheets-in-other-workbooks)